# How to insert a data point at a time to a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

It might be non-pythonic (if yes, let me know also) but I am running a function that produces only one data point at a time, and I would like to add those points to my dataframe. The reason for this is that for each row, I have 252 rows (in another dataframe) that I will input in a function, and will return me a single number.

I am using this method:

```
data.loc[row, 'ColumnA'] = some integer
```

but it appends the rows/values at the end of the dataframe, when I want to create a new column and populate it a data point at a time. So, for example, if I have this column in a dataframe:

```
Column A
NaN
NaN
NaN
```

and I run this:

```
data.loc[0, 'ColumnA'] = 10
```

I would like to see:

```
Column A
10
NaN
NaN
```

Thank you!

Comment: is there a reason you want to append to the dataframe one point at a time? It would probably be better to run the function on all values and add it as a column in a vectorized fashion...

Comment: It sounds like your dataframe's row index may not be the sequence 0, 1, 2, ...? Can you paste the output of `print(data)` or at least `data.head()`?

Comment: @Ben I reset my index and it worked, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `.at` function on a dataframe 
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.at.html

It can be used to look at and change the value using a row/column pair
`df.at[row, column] = value`
So your code would look like
`data.at[row, 'columnA'] = 10`